# how to get all change lists of a user in sourceTree?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

Is there any way to filter or search for all change lists of a specific user in sourceTree?

I want to choose a branch and see only the pushes of a specific user.

Comment: Not sure how this question is too broad.  `Is there any way?` is a yes / no answer.  Or at worst a "yes, but".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do basic searches on the Search tab of [atlassian-sourcetree](/questions/tagged/atlassian-sourcetree).  You can search by user, although it doesn't give you a list so you'll need to type it manually.  Also, it doesn't look like you can filter by branch unfortunately:

[image: Screenshot]

So it seams for your specific use case you'll be better served by another tool.  [TurtoiseGit](https://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/) for windows, for example, can do this.

Right click on the folder containing your project and navigate to *Open Log*.  From the Log view you can filter by branch and then query by user:

[image]